# Can I use Project Online as a dev environment for CSOM

Tags: csom, project-server, project-web-access

I need to write a .NET client app that accesses Project Server 2013.  I.e. PWA.  That client app must run on Windows 7 workstations.  I plan to use Project Server Client Side Object Model (CSOM) to access all the projects, tasks, resources, and assignments in Project Server.

Q1: Can I sign up for Project Online and use it to test my client app?

Q2: Will it act exactly like the on-premise installations of PWA?

Q3: If my client app works with Project Online, will it likely work with on-premise PWA installations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: Can I sign up for Project Online and use it to test my client app?

Yes, just go ahead and [setup your Office 365 development environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/setup-development-environment).

> Q2: Will it act exactly like the on-premise installations of PWA?

In respect to CSOM API, yes.

> Q3: If my client app works with Project Online, will it likely work with on-premise PWA installations?

Yes. However, on-premise SharePoint (and Project Server) deployments have to be [configured](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/01/31/configuring-sharepoint-on-premise-deployments-for-apps.aspx) to allow access by an App for SharePoint using CSOM.

Comment: Is an Office 365 account necessary?  Can't I just sign up for Project Online and begin using the Project 2013 SDK to access PWA?

Comment: This was the correct answer.  I only have 12 reputation at this time, so I can't +1, but this was all correct.

Comment: @RayWhite You can accept it as an answer regardless of reputation.